# Using a Boot to VHD file in a Hyper-V Server VM

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd

I have a file win7.vhd that I've been using in a Boot to VHD scenario. Now I want to run that Windows 7 instance within Hyper-V Server alongside a few other VMs I have. I sysprepped  win7.vhd and copied it over to the the Hyper-V Server and tried creating a new VM using that .vhd file. I get the "Boot failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device" error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully boot my vhd in Hyper-V Server using the sequence of commands found at http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=317

- Boot into a Windows 7 Installation disc. When the wizard begins, open a command prompt by pressing Shift+F10
- Open Diskpart
- Select vdisk file=D:\Win7.VHD
- Attach Vdisk
- select part 1
- active
- Assign letter=Z
- exit
- Now, at the command prompt, change to Z:\Windows\System32
- Run, BCDboot.exe Z:\Windows /s Z:\
- Run, BCDedit /store Z:\boot\BCD /set {bootmgr} device boot
- Run, BCDedit /store Z:\boot\BCD /set {default} device boot
- Run, BCDedit /store Z:\boot\BCD /set {default} osdevice boot
- Change directory to C:\
- open Diskpart again and run
- Select vdisk file=D:\Win7.VHD
- detach vDISK
- Exit

Comment: It sounds like you set up your VM to boot from a VHD from within the VM.  I was suggesting that you make the VHD itself the boot volume of the VM.  Either way, you seem to have what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot (physically) from a VHD, the boot loader and a few other files reside not within the VHD but on the hosting volume, thus the VHD is incomplete when it stands alone (virtually, within a VM.)

You can probably fix it up by booting the VM from the Windows 7 installation CD and telling it to repair the boot volume.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you mean by "booting the VM from the Windows 7 installation CD" could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant:  Attach the Windows 7 DVD (or an ISO file that contains the same thing) to your VM.  Configure the VM to boot from the CD.  Press the "start" button on the VM.